# jQuery slide effect

Tags: jquery, animation, slide

I'm looking for a slide effect for a navigation. But in my opinion the slide effect of jQuery is a little strange, or doesn't really fit my needs. The list items kind of appear but aren't animated (the container is only animated) when I apply the slideDown,slideUp,toggleSlide effect. I would like to have the list items animated as well.

I've found an example of this: http://www.creative-exposure.co.uk/

If you someone could help me out, I would really appreciate it.

yours truthfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps here is a link to the forum the site was posted on for critique by the original designer  http://www.estetica-design-forum.com/graphic-design-web-design-critique/19701-wedding-photography-kent.html
  You could always go there and ask him directly

Theresa

Answer (score 0):

`.slideDown()` should produce that effect if used on the `<ul>`.  But, if you're looking for a full menu package, I'd check out the [Superfish plugin](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/), you can just layout your menu as a `<ul>` and `<li>` hierarchy and let it take care of the rest.

Use the `animation: {height:'show'}` option for the vertical slide down like the page you linked, [see here for an example](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#sample3) (this is vertical, but it can be the same on a horizontal menu).

Answer (score 0):

If you check out on cssdrive.com under the menu bit, it should be on there how the navigation on my website was made.

Regards

Theresa (creative-exposure)

Comment: thanks for the link but I haven't really found a useful link, if you can will you link me please?